# How to create multiple figures without showing them until plt.show is called?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'd like to be able to independently create multiple figures with different graphs and choose whether they will be displayed in the GUI and or instead instead saved using the `plt.savefig()` function. (Most of the time I think I want them all to be displayed AND saved or none to be displayed only saved)

I am trying to create a function called `plotData(channel, refFile)` which gets passed a a couple of parameters and creates a matplotlib figure and plots some data to it. I do not want the figure to be shown until I call another function `showPlot(channel)` which would show a the corresponding figure when called.

Unfortunately whenever I use the plt.figure() function it automatically displays the figure. I've seen some answers from similar questions where people try something like `plt.figure(visible=False)` or `plt.figure('visibility', 'off')` but neither of these worked for me.

```
def plotData(self, chan, refFile):

    #create figure without showing the gui window
    self.figure[chan-1]=plt.figure()

    #plot data to graph
    sigPlot, =plt.plot(self.time[chan-1],self.yAxis[chan-1], label='Measured Signal')
    refPlot,= plt.plot(self.time[chan-1],self.refSig[chan-1], label='Reference Signal')
    plt.legend(handles=[sigPlot, refPlot])

def showPlot(self,chan):
    self.figure[chan-1].show()


def savePlot(self, filename):
    plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Also how would do I save a particular plot? I don't mind if I always have to simply call the save figure plot function before creating the same plot.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use `plt.ioff()` initially to switch off interactive mode.

This done, you are free to `plt.savefig()` your figure after you created it with calling `plt.show()` before or without it. And then you can close it via `plt.close()`, independently if it was shown before or invisibly saved to a file (or even created without both showing or saving...)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know is there a way of pausing the script before the end until the figures get closed? I'm pretty sure that's the behaviour I've seen normally. I'm plotting these figures within a pytest test script, I don't know if that changes things. I've tried turnning interative mode back on at the end with plt.ion() but that didn't work.

Comment: @genericpurpleturtle I think I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve and how. I didn't work with pytest up to now, but I'd doubt that this affects your target. However, are you working within an IDE like e.g. Spyder? E.g. if I start a script in Spyder creating some (eventually invisible) figures, I still have access to them in my related console.

Comment: I'm working in visual studio community edition 2017. I basically want the script to pause until the figure is closed. I think `plot.show(block=True)` seems to work pause the script, but then it crashes when I close the window. It works as expected when I run it from the command line though. Seems to be an issue with visual studio.